# Google AI platform Error: Could not parse the line, not a valid json: Cannot find field: text_snippet in message

Tags: google-ai-platform

I'm trying to upload import files from my computer and get an error.
My jsonl file contents:

```
{"text_snippet": {"content": "whatever"}}
```

Why cannot find field: `text_snippet` in message?